# Lookup a Value from a range, and return the cell reference address

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, lookup

Working in Google sheets and want to lookup a value (in cell U355) and search for it in the range (F3:R650)
The Value is in cell L412 and I want L412 to be the result.
Played with INDEX/MATCH, LOOKUP, FIND, CELL etc. but don't seem to be able to get the correct combination as they don't like 2 dimensional ranges.

I can use COUNTIF to confirm that the value is there, but want to know exactly where it is.
If it makes any difference, the value will be in Columns F,I,L,O,R

Many thanks

Comment: Can you show the layout of your sheet?

Comment: Thanks Christoffer - sheet link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DAU9TGHv9UMZ_PrynrCUky73utwzjcn0MN9mZeBn8N8/edit?usp=sharing  I have removed a lot of info from it for privacy and it is a copy, but the cell I want to look up is now U4, and find the cell L89

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
=iferror(arrayformula(split(query(flatten(column(F3:R325)*(F3:R325=U4)&"-"&row(F3:R325)*(F3:R325=U4)),"select * where Col1<>'0-0'"),"-")),)
```

the result will be `15 | 55` that means value has been retrieved in column 15 (O) line 55
[image]

Comment: Many thanks Mike - need to get my head around it but it seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(U4:U5, {FLATTEN(F3:R), 
 VLOOKUP(1*FLATTEN(COLUMN(F3:R)&IFERROR(ROW(F3:R)/0)), 
 {SEQUENCE(26), CHAR(ROW(65:90))}, 2, 0)&
 FLATTEN(ROW(F3:R)&IFERROR(COLUMN(F3:R)/0))}, 2, 0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

using ADDRESS as the strategy:

```
=ADDRESS(SUMPRODUCT(ROW(range)*(range=value)),SUMPRODUCT(COLUMN(range)*(range=value)))
```

your formula would become:

```
=ADDRESS(SUMPRODUCT(ROW($F$3:$R$325)*($F$3:$R$325=U4)),SUMPRODUCT(COLUMN($F$3:$R$325)*($F$3:$R$325=U4)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mr Shane - that is helpful and seems to be the neatest/most straightforward

Answer (score 0):

Using a LAMBDA function:

```
=SORTN(FLATTEN(MAP(F3:R,LAMBDA(x,IF(x=U4,CELL("address",x),)))))
```